# Make custom page-based loop in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I would like to create another page-based loop, in the same way the `_posts` folder works for the blog section, but for a small catalogue of magazines. (Hopefully that makes sense)

Maybe i'm misunderstanding something simple, but I just can't work it out.
I have this loop, which feels like it should work, but nothing gets returned.

```
{% for page in site.pressitems %}
<li>
    <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Code, links, explanation, anything is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't add your own collection to `site` just like that.

`site` only knows about three collections: `pages`, `posts`, and `categories`. You can get all the posts of a category by doing `site.<category>.posts` . AFAIK, categories only work for posts, not pages.

This makes sense, since Jekyll is supposed to be mainly a blogging engine, and not a generic static website generator.

So your best solution right now consists on "lying" to jekyll. Make it believe you have posts, when in reality you are making pages.

```
_posts/
  pressitems/
  blog/
```

You will be able to loop over the elements inside _posts/pressitems like this:

```
for item in site.categories.pressitems.posts do
  ... {{ item.title }} ... {{ item.url }}
endfor
```

Similarly, your "real blog entries" would go this way:

```
for p in site.categories.blog.posts do
  ... {{ p.title }} ... {{ p.url }}
endfor
```

The catch is that you will have to respect Jekyll's naming convention regarding filenames; your pressitems have to look like real posts. This means they have to be named starting with a yyyy-mm-dd- string, like posts. Just give them a random date.

```
_posts/
  pressitems/
    1901-01-01-the-first-press-item.textile
    1902-01-01-the-second-one.textile
```

EDIT: This was true when this post was originally written, in 2012, but not any more. Modern Jekyll does allow you to create your own collections https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/

Comment: I think it should be `endfor`, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Besides simply outputting pages, posts and collections `site` object also contains some specialized collections you may use including `html_pages`, `html_files` and `static_files` for example. Always reference the docs for the latest: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/.

Answer (score 18):

You can iterate through `site.pages`

```
{% for page in site.pages %}
  <h3><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></h3>
  <p>{{ page.content }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

And limit the list the only pages that use a particular layout.

```
{% for page in site.pages %}
  {% if page.layout == 'team' %}  
    <h3><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></h3>
    <p>{{ page.content }}</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

See this post about generating a sitemap:
http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/jekyll/jekyll-sitemap-without-plugins/

Comment: Very useful, thanks. I've adapted this for my own use case: listing _other_ pages on the site. To do so I've added the condition `page.permalink != p.permalink` (using `p` as the iterator value rather than `page` to avoid a namespace conflict).

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks! A little bit of `if` logic here goes a long way

Answer (score 13):

## As of `October 2016`:

In Jekyll 2.5.3 you can actually *can* add your own [collection](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) to site.

Add `_my_collection` folder to root and fill with documents.
Add to `_config.yml`:

```
collections:
- my_collection
```

Now call documents using either post, page, or category.
e.g.
`{ for post in site.my_collection
< do something > }`

It is important to note that this feature can be used it has been marked by the Jekyll team as "an experimental feature and the API may change until the feature stabilizes".

Answer (score 5):

On jekyll you can also add yaml front-matter to pages. There's nothing wrong with adding custom front-matter, like page-category.

```
---
layout: plain
title: "My beautiful page"
description: ""
snippet: ""
page-category: "category 1"
---
```

access them via:

```
{% for page in site.pages %}
   {% if page.page-category == "category 1" %}
        {{ page.content }}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```